# Rspec/Guard/FactoryGirl returning erroneous 'undefined method' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, guard, spork

First, I have a valid factory/model, and this particular test runs fine through the console.

### model

```
validate :some_condition

def some_condition
  errors.add(:attribute, "cannot be less than 5") if self.attribute < 5
end
```

### test

```
it "should not allow values above 5" do
  model = FactoryGirl.create(:model) # creates valid model
  model.attribute = 10
  model.valid?.should be_false
end
```

#### In the console:

```
model = FactoryGirl.create(:model)
model.attribute = 10
model.valid? # => false
```

#### In rspec

```
undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass
```

I cannot fathom why this is happening. It is obviously something to do with `self.attribute`, but why would it work in the console, yet not in the tests? `attribute` alone also returns same error, and I've checked, - self is defined as model instance. Regardless, this doesn't explain the inconsistency. It works in the console with exactly the same model and attributes.

To note: I have restarted all environments, this is based on a fresh reload.

#### update

In an act of desperation, I have outputted `attribute` in several contexts before this condition, and then `exit`. This has brought with it even stranger results. Work this out:

```
def some_condition
  puts self.attribute # => returns blank in test, attribute value otherwise
  puts "#{self.attribute}" # => returns attribute value in test!!!
  exit

  errors.add(:attribute, "cannot be less than 5") if self.attribute < 5
end
```

The above has made me incredibly tense. Do I now need tests to test my tests?  really hope someone more experienced in ruby or the above tools has some logical explanation for this mess, because I'm completely lost.

It leads to this abomination:

```
errors.add(:attribute, "cannot be less than 5") if self.attribute < 5
# => IN TESTS self.attribute returns nil

errors.add(:attribute, "cannot be less than 5") if "#{self.attribute}".to_i < 5
# => IN TESTS self.attribute returns value! This works!?
```

Where do you even turn? Is it ruby, rails, factory girl, rspec?

#### FIX

After that massive wreck of a question, it turns out I forgot to `rake db:test:prepare` after a minor migration. I'm still baffled as to how it could have caused such an issue. Lesson learned. Run migrations across environments, and find a better debugger!

Comment: Your `if` conditional in the validator looks wrong, is that just a copy-paste error?

Comment: It is, I'll fix that now.

Comment: *I can't really share all of the code*. I can't speak for other SO users, but this is a red flag for me. If you can't (for whatever reason) share the actual code that produces the error, I suggest creating an example that also produces the error which you *can* share. This may also help you narrow down the cause, in case there is something unusual about your configuration.

Comment: use -b to run the tests, so you can have a full stacktrace, maybe that helps to see where the error is coming from

Comment: also, if your validation is actually attr < some value, check the numericallity validator, you have a grated_than option http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#numericality

Comment: @zetetic I can't share all of the code because it would completely detract from the point - this structure above doesn't work. Do you want to wade through a mile of code to understand that? I can't speak for other SO users, but when I browse complicated questions, I am *always* thankful for smaller code chunks to increase brevity. What do you think this code above does? It does produce the error..?

Comment: @zetetic please do tell me what could be wrong with my configuration that could cause `self.attribute` to evaluate to nil, but `"#{self.attribute}"` evaluate to correct value (10, in this case).

Comment: @arieljuod thanks, I'll have a closer look.

Comment: Did you have an integer column declared as a string? That happened to me once. Took hours to figure out. :)

As for my earlier suggestion, what I was trying to get at was: start from scratch. Build up the simplest test case you can that reproduces the problem,  even creating an entirely new app if you have to. At some point you will re-introduce the code/configuration/gem/whatever that causes the fault.

Comment: @zetetic that `db:test:prepare` is a hard catch! Won't be making that subtle mistake again. To the contrare, I had a field set as string which should have been an integer and so created a migration. Good point re debugging flow. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The RSpec syntax has changed a bit from versions 1 to 2 and that can muddle things up.

Could you tell me what happens if you write your test exactly like this?

```
it "should not allow values above 5" do
  model = build(:model, :attribute => 10)
  model.should_not be_valid
  model.should have(1).error_on(:attribute)
end
```

The reason I'm using `build` rather than `create` is that way you can test your validations without hitting the database.

Comment: Trouble is, my above example is a heavily simplified example. This doesn't answer two important things: 1) factories/tests work manually in console, yet not in tests, and 2), `self.attribute` returns nil, yet `"#{self.attribute}"` returns correct value. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why that happens and it is indeed an abomination. I'm going to direct more capable people to this question.

Comment: I'd greatly appreciate that, thanks. I suspect it is because the attribute is being called from two different locations, depending on interpolation. Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Turns out I forgot to `rake db:test:prepare`, and that produced this odd error. Amateur, I know. Out of interest, do you know of a possible debugging tool that might have caught this (apart from my broken brain)?

Comment: Hey, it happens. I had my share of forgetting to run that as well. As for debugging tools, nope, don't know 'em.